# Installation ncurses to run command menu config

Tags: kernel, system-installation

I am trying to upload new kernel apart from default one.
but while installing ncurses getting error
I tried with following options

1) `sudo apt-get install ncurses-dev`
then got error

```
404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.201 80]
```

2) `sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list`

and change souce page to in.old-releases.ubuntu.com

3) `sudo apt-get install ncurses-dev`

```
error : Package 'ncurses-dev' has no installation candidate
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run

```
sudo apt-get update
```

after you change the urls to old.releases.ubuntu.com to update the package list.

Comment: @erdarshp you're welcome. please accept the answer by clicking the icon on the left to close the question out

Answer (score 2):

Installing libncurses-dev solved this problem for me on ubuntu-mate 16.04.1 as of Fri Aug 19 with a fully updated system.

Answer (score -1):

This should work for you:

```
sudo apt-get install libncurses-dev
```

Comment: The OP said specifically that this command didn't work.

Comment: @Parto my read of the question was that the op was trying to install `ncurses-dev`, not `libncurses-dev`